# i have problems with my connect_four.pl program

Tags: prolog

I'm working on a Prolog program for a class project and I'm running into a syntax error on line 74 when I try to compile it using GNU Prolog version 1.4.5. The code runs without any issues when I use SWI-Prolog, but my professor requires us to use GNU Prolog for the assignment. Here's the error message I'm getting:
C:/Users/steff/Desktop/Progetto_PLF_2023_Elia_Stefanini/Forza4 - Copia.pl:74:17: syntax error: current or previous operator needs brackets
1 error(s)
compilation failed.

I've checked for missing operators and parentheses, but I can't seem to find the issue. Could someone please take a look at my code and help me identify the problem? I've attached the relevant section of code below.

```
% Inizializza la griglia di gioco
init_grid([
    ['-','-','-','-','-','-'],
    ['-','-','-','-','-','-'],
    ['-','-','-','-','-','-'],
    ['-','-','-','-','-','-'],
    ['-','-','-','-','-','-'],
    ['-','-','-','-','-','-']
]).

% Stampa la griglia di gioco
print_grid([]).
print_grid([Row|Rest]) :-
    write(Row), nl,
    print_grid(Rest).

% Stampa la griglia di gioco ruotata di 90 gradi in senso antiorario
print_rotated_grid(Grid) :-
    rotate_grid(Grid, RotatedGrid),
    print_grid(RotatedGrid).

% Ruota la griglia di gioco di 90 gradi in senso antiorario
rotate_grid(Grid, RotatedGrid) :-
    transpose(Grid, Transposed),
    reverse(Transposed, RotatedGrid).

% Calcola la trasposizione di una matrice
transpose([], []).
transpose([F|Fs], Ts) :-
    transpose(F, [F|Fs], Ts).

transpose([], _, []).
transpose([_|Rs], Ms, [Ts|Tss]) :-
    lists_firsts_rests(Ms, Ts, Ms1),
    transpose(Rs, Ms1, Tss).

% Estrae i primi elementi e i restanti elementi dalle liste
lists_firsts_rests([], [], []).
lists_firsts_rests([[F|R]|Ls], [F|Fs], [R|Rs]) :-
    lists_firsts_rests(Ls, Fs, Rs).

% Verifica se un input è valido (un intero compreso tra 1 e 6)
valid_input(Input) :-
    integer(Input),
    between(1, 6, Input).

% Chiede all'utente di scegliere una colonna
choose_column(Column) :-
    write('Inserisci un numero tra 1 e 6: '),
    read(Input),
    (
        valid_input(Input) ->
        Column = Input;
        writeln('Input non valido. Riprova.'),
        choose_column(Column)
    ).

% Inserisce il gettone del giocatore nella griglia
insert_token(Grid, Column, Player, NewGrid) :-
    insert_token_col(Grid, Column, Player, 1, NewGrid).

insert_token_col([], _, _, _, []).
insert_token_col([Row|Rest], Column, Player, Column, [NewRow|Rest]) :-
    replace_first_free(Row, Player, NewRow),
    NewRow \= Row.
insert_token_col([Row|Rest], Column, Player, RowIndex, [Row|NewRest]) :-
    RowIndex \== Column,
    NewRowIndex is RowIndex + 1,
    insert_token_col(Rest, Column, Player, NewRowIndex, NewRest).

% Sostituisce la prima cella libera con il gettone del giocatore
replace_first_free(['-'|Rest], Player, [Player|Rest]) :- !.
replace_first_free([Cell|Rest], Player, [Cell|NewRest]) :-
    Cell \== '-',
    replace_first_free(Rest, Player, NewRest).

% Le direzioni possibili per controllare la vittoria
directions([
    [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, -1]
]).

% Verifica se un giocatore ha vinto
player_won(Grid, Player) :-
    directions(Directions),
    member(Dir, Directions),
    won(Grid, Player, Dir).

% Controlla se un giocatore ha vinto in una specifica direzione
won(Grid, Player, [RowDir, ColDir]) :-
    between(1, 6, Row),
    between(1, 6, Col),
    check_line(Grid, Player, Row, Col, RowDir, ColDir, 4).

% Controlla una linea di gettoni dello stesso giocatore
check_line(Grid, Player, Row, Col, RowDir, ColDir, Count) :-
    Count > 0,
    cell(Grid, Row, Col, Player),
    NextRow is Row + RowDir,
    NextCol is Col + ColDir,
    NewCount is Count - 1,
    check_line(Grid, Player, NextRow, NextCol, RowDir, ColDir, NewCount).

check_line(_, _, _, _, _, _, 0).

% Verifica se una cella contiene il gettone di un giocatore
cell(Grid, Row, Col, Player) :-
    between(1, 6, Row),
    between(1, 6, Col),
    nth1(Col, Grid, ColList),
    nth1(Row, ColList, Player).

% Verifica se la partita termina in pareggio
draw(Grid) :-
    \+ (member(Row, Grid), member('-', Row)).

% Esegue il turno di un giocatore
play_turn(Grid, Player) :-
    print_rotated_grid(Grid),
    format('Turno del giocatore ~w\n', [Player]),
    choose_column(Column),
    (
        insert_token(Grid, Column, Player, NewGrid) ->
        (
            player_won(NewGrid, Player) ->
            print_rotated_grid(NewGrid),
            format('Il giocatore ~w ha vinto!\n', [Player]),
            nl;
            draw(NewGrid) ->
            print_rotated_grid(NewGrid),
            writeln('Pareggio!'),
            nl;
            switch_player(Player, NextPlayer),
            play_turn(NewGrid, NextPlayer)
        );
        writeln('Colonna piena. Riprova.'),
        play_turn(Grid, Player)
    ).

% Cambia il giocatore
switch_player('X', 'O').
switch_player('O', 'X').

% Chiede all'utente se vuole rigiocare
play_again :-
    write('Vuoi rigiocare? (s/n) '),
    read(Input),
    (
        member(Input, ['s', 'n']) ->
        Input = 's';
        writeln('Input non valido. Riprova.'),
        play_again
    ).

% Funzione principale del programma
main :-
    init_grid(Grid),
    play_turn(Grid, 'X'),
    (
        play_again ->
        main;
        writeln('Grazie per aver giocato!')
    ).

% Inizializza il programma
:- initialization(main).
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

I've searched various online forums, including chatbots like GPT, but so far I haven't been able to find a solution. Could someone please take a look at my code and help me identify the problem?

Comment: That `:74:17:` means take a look at **line 74**, character 17. If you're showing us a snippet, then identify line 74 to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an operator is an operand of another operator it needs brackets. Change line 74:

```
Cell \== '-',
```

by

```
Cell \== (-),
```

Note that, the atom `-` does not need quotes.

Then define a `writeln/1` predicate as

```
writeln(X) :-
        write(X),
        nl.
```

Comment: wooooow it works thank you, you save me<3

Comment: How/why is `'-'` being seen as an operator here, isn't it a quoted atom?

Comment: Indeed, `-` is an atom (all operators are atoms). It is also defined as an infix (binary) operator allowing to write the term `-(3, 2)` as `3 - 2` (which is more readable). It does not need quotes, they are optional, i.e. in other words, this query succeeds `('-') = (-)`

Comment: You do not need the quotes! Write `Cell \== (-)` in stead. Also replace `['-','-'|...]` by `[-,-|...]`. And even more compactly by using the directive `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,chars).` Then, a list of minuses like `['-','-','-','-','-','-']` becomes `"------"`.